# TitaniumStudio studio login Error?

Tags: java, ssl

i am facing problem login to `Titanium` `Studio` , i got this message

`the login to server return error`

I've installed latest version of Java same problem .

also i am lunching studio from terminal still same problem

```
Khodours-MacBook-Pro:MacOS Jack$ sudo ./TitaniumStudio
Password:
!SESSION 2015-07-25 21:52:18.318 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_65
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/Jack/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -keyring /Users/Jack/.eclipse_keyring -consoleLog -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.net 1 0 2015-07-25 21:52:21.098
!MESSAGE System property http.nonProxyHosts has been set to local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16 by an external source. This value will be overwritten using the values from the preferences
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.signIn(TitaniumUserManager.java:224)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler$12.run(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:780)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1691)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1222)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:476)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.createOutputStream(TitaniumUserManager.java:253)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.signIn(TitaniumUserManager.java:166)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:114)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:559)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:186)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DashoA13*..)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:627)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:107)
    ... 15 more
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.signIn(TitaniumUserManager.java:224)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler$12.run(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:780)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1691)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1222)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:476)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.createOutputStream(TitaniumUserManager.java:253)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.signIn(TitaniumUserManager.java:166)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:114)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:559)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:186)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DashoA13*..)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:627)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:107)
    ... 15 more
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.signIn(TitaniumUserManager.java:224)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler$12.run(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:780)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1691)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1222)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:476)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.createOutputStream(TitaniumUserManager.java:253)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.signIn(TitaniumUserManager.java:166)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:114)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:559)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:186)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DashoA13*..)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:627)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:107)
    ... 15 more
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.signIn(TitaniumUserManager.java:224)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler$12.run(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:780)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1708)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1691)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1222)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1199)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:476)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:166)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1031)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:230)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.createOutputStream(TitaniumUserManager.java:253)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.user.TitaniumUserManager.signIn(TitaniumUserManager.java:166)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not generate DH keypair
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:114)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:559)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:186)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:943)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1215)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Prime size must be multiple of 64, and can only range from 512 to 1024 (inclusive)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DHKeyPairGenerator.initialize(DashoA13*..)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.initialize(KeyPairGenerator.java:627)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DHCrypt.<init>(DHCrypt.java:107)
    ... 15 more
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download bouncy castle jar here:
http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar

Copy jar file to:
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ext/

Edit:
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/java.security

Add the following line where other security providers are defined:
security.provider.11=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

Restart Titanium Studio

Comment: @amon, i have similar problem with my MAC, i am not able to find the destination path u mentioned for bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar file. /system/library/java folder contains "Extensions" & "Support" folders only. I have updated "javaforosx.dmg" to 2015 version

Comment: @JRC i think you should enable show hidden files in Finder

Comment: ls -la doesn't show that either. I'm using OS X 10.10.4

Answer (score 2):

finally after spending lots of hours and trying allot of examples none worked

the only solution worked with me is to edit  `TitaniumStudio.ini` located in `/Applications/Titanium_Studio/TitaniumStudio/Contents/MacOS` and add :

```
-Dtitanium.bypassAuthentication=true
```